# How to remove all the unsed imports from a React Js project? (VSCode)

Tags: reactjs, import, visual-studio-code

How do i remove un-used imports from all my files in **Visual Studio Code**, my warning console looks like this

[image: Warning Console]

I have tried useing `shift+alt+o` but that only removes imports from the current file

Comment: You haven't tried going through it manually and fixing each issue?

Comment: Similar question:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722701/is-there-a-way-to-remove-unused-imports-and-declarations-from-angular-2

Comment: @AmanGupta Like i said `shift+alt+o` only removes the unused imports from the **Current** file

Comment: @rrd it is really not feasable when you have like 20 different files, a lot of time is wasted over a period of time

Comment: Even going through 100 files and pressing shift-alt-o is unlikely to take more than 5 minutes, and you only need to do it once ... not sure what the problem is ... ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an eslint plugin for that. It works fine with me.

It's called [eslint-plugin-unused-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-unused-imports).

In the file for eslint configuration:

```
"plugins": ["unused-imports"],
"rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "off", // or "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
    "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error",
    "unused-imports/no-unused-vars": [
        "warn",
        { "vars": "all", "varsIgnorePattern": "^_", "args": "after-used", "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }
    ]
}
```

Then, on your vscode config:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
},
```

I hope it helps.