# How to remove unused require and/or import lines?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Let's take this file :

```
const foo = require('./bar')
```

***foo*** is not used anymore.

How to automatically remove this line from the file ? Is there any command for that job ?

Comment: I will not answer your question, but, with VS Code (and maybe an extension), you can see unused variables and functions in your file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS code then go to one unused declaration then press `Ctrl+.`. Or hover over it and It will a show quick fix option. Click on it then select the `Delete all unused declaration`.

Or if you're using `vim/nvim` with `coc.vim` use the `<leader>qf` shortcut to do a quick fix.

### Edit

I found that this question has already been answered here [Is there a way to remove unused imports and declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722701/is-there-a-way-to-remove-unused-imports-and-declarations-from-angular-2#46722805)

Comment: Sorry in that case I don't know how to help you :-/