# Is it possible to remove unused imports with Prettier?

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint, prettier

I have an Expo React Native app that has a ton of unused imports in components.

I have Prettier setup for code formatting, is it possible to configure Prettier to also remove any unused imports across the project?

I can't see anything in the docs and I don't know if there is a way to add extra eslint plugins to Prettier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to remove unused imports and declarations from Angular 2+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722701/is-there-a-way-to-remove-unused-imports-and-declarations-from-angular-2)

Comment: @abolfazlshamsollahi No it doesn't because I don't use VSCode

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think this is supported by default.

But you can use this prettier-plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier-plugin-organize-imports

Comment: Great tip! Very simple to install and no configuration needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

You can use VS Code `.vscode/settings.json` to organize imports.

```json
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.organizeImports": true
}
```

Comment: **2024 UPDATE:**
As per [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_organize-imports), 
`"source.organizeImports": true` changed to `"source.organizeImports": "explicit"` and instead of `false` now it's `never`.
check the link for more details.